# How to write regular javascript and load online external library in vue.js components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, gio, external-js

I'm creating a website with vue.Js (vue.cli) to show some of my work.

Actually all the interactions and experiments are made in a iframe, because I don't understand how to load and use external javascript

For example in one of my components I would like to use gio.js.
To use it you need to call 4 libraries:

- jquery -> https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
- three.js -> https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js
- gio.js -> https://raw.githack.com/syt123450/giojs/master/build/gio.min.js
- data -> https://raw.githack.com/syt123450/giojs/master/assets/data/sampleData.js

So actually I write that in my component, but nothing works:

So, I would like to proper load external js files, and write regular js in my components or in an externals files.

```
<template>
  <div class="planet"> 
//globalArea is for render the planisphere
 <div id="globalArea"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
 let jqueryScript = document.createElement('script')
    jqueryScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js')
    document.head.appendChild(jqueryScript);
   let threeScript = document.createElement('script')
    threeScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js')
    document.head.appendChild(threeScript);
 let gioScript = document.createElement('script')
    gioScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://raw.githack.com/syt123450/giojs/master/build/gio.min.js')
    document.head.appendChild(gioScript);
     let dataScript = document.createElement('script')
    dataScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://raw.githack.com/syt123450/giojs/master/assets/data/sampleData.js"')
    document.head.appendChild(dataScript);
  }
  methods: {
// Get the container to hold the IO globe
var container = document.getElementById( "globalArea" );
// Create Gio.controller
var controller = new GIO.Controller( container );
// Add data
controller.addData( data );
// Initialize and render the globe
controller.init();

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you building your project with single-file components, or you are using Vue compiler with inline HTML templates ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a common error, the `methods` properties is an object that carries all the methods you want to define for example:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    myFirstMethod () {
      //code goes here
    },
    mySecondMethod () {
      //code goes here
    },
  }
}
```

If you want to initialize your data when the component is shown you can load the scripts on the `beforeCreate` hook and paste your code on the `mounted` hook. Here is how it should look:

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  beforeCreate() {
    let jqueryScript = document.createElement('script')
    jqueryScript.setAttribute('src', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js')
    document.head.appendChild(jqueryScript);
    let threeScript = document.createElement('script')
    threeScript.setAttribute('src', '//threejs.org/build/three.min.js')
    document.head.appendChild(threeScript);
    let gioScript = document.createElement('script')
    gioScript.setAttribute('src', '//raw.githack.com/syt123450/giojs/master/build/gio.min.js')
    document.head.appendChild(gioScript);
    let dataScript = document.createElement('script')
    dataScript.setAttribute('src', '//raw.githack.com/syt123450/giojs/master/assets/data/sampleData.js')
    document.head.appendChild(dataScript);
  },
  mounted() {
  
    setTimeout(() => {
        // Get the container to hold the IO globe
      var container = document.getElementById( "globalArea" );
      // Create Gio.controller
      var controller = new GIO.Controller( container );
      // Add data
      controller.addData( data );
      // Initialize and render the globe
      controller.init();
    }, 2000)
    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="planet"> 
    //globalArea is for render the planisphere
    <div id="globalArea" style="height: 500px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also keep in mind that you can only access those scripts when they are fully loaded, that's why I'm using a setTimeout with 2 seconds of delay.